# Android strike-through animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to do this strike-through animation to my icon, however I cannot figure out how to do it properly. Now I have the icon and the animation all prepared:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="125dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100.0"
    android:viewportHeight="125.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M50,77.4l-26.3,13.8l5.1,-29.2l-21.3,-20.7l29.4,-4.3l13.1,-26.6l13.1,26.6l29.4,4.3l-21.3,20.7l5.1,29.2z"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M89.08,10.75 L7.36,90.99"
    android:strokeLineCap="butt"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
    android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
</vector>
```

The above xml looks like this:
[image]

Now I want the image to not contain the strike initially. Then when the user clicks on the image, the strike should animate. How can I do this? How can I 'hide' the strike at the beginning?

The animation is the following:

```
<objectAnimator
  android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
  android:valueType="floatType"
  android:valueFrom="1"
  android:valueTo="0"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
  android:duration="250"
/>
```

Now, I thought about first using an image without the strike, then animating a strike into it, then switching the img src to the one with the strike. But then again, I have the same problem, how can I animate the strike without showing it all initially.

Comment: can you show a sample of animation you want?

Comment: I've edited my question to contain more info @VladMatvienko

Comment: How about having that stroke line as a seperate view ? That way you would have much more controll over it